# How to compress high resolution image bytes without converting to an image/bitmap first

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, compression, kinect

I'm working with the Kinect 2.0 and in particular with the color stream.  The color stream arrives with a whooping 1920×1080 resolution, which is great! Except, I intend to capture the image bytes and write them to disk.  So, the most viable solution for me is to compress each image frame and then store the compressed image rather than the raw high resolution image.

I have a solution but I feel its a bit of a "round the houses" way of doing this.

Basically, I get the raw pixels, write them to a WriteableBitmap and then compress the ImageSource using the following two methods:

1) Write to WriteableBitmap:

```
this.colorBitmap.WritePixels(
                new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight),
                this.colorPixels,
                this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth * (int)this.bytesPerPixel,
                0);
```

2) Compress this to jpeg:

```
        public static byte[] CompressToBytes(ImageSource src, int compressionrate)
        {                  
            var enc = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            enc.QualityLevel = compressionrate;

            var bf = BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)src);
            enc.Frames.Add(bf);

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                enc.Save(ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Which works fine, as I said, but I think it would be much better if I could get the raw pixels from the Kinect and then directly compress byte array rather than writing to a WriteableBitmap and then compressing that.  Just seems like an extra step.

BTW, this is the code I use to grab the bytes from the color frame:

```
    using (ColorFrame colorFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
    {
        if (colorFrame != null)
        {
            FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = colorFrame.FrameDescription;

            if ((colorFrameDescription.Width == this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth) && (colorFrameDescription.Height == this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight))
            {
                if (colorFrame.RawColorImageFormat == ColorImageFormat.Bgra)
                {
                    colorFrame.CopyRawFrameDataToArray(this.colorPixels);
                }
                else
                {
                    colorFrame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray(this.colorPixels, ColorImageFormat.Bgra);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Baring in mind that when working with the color stream at all the number of frames per second you are able to capture drops, (from say 30-32 to 26-29 roughly), I want to use the most efficient way.

One thing I've noticed that when searching for compression solutions in c#, is that a good percentage of articles are aimed at storing a single image to disk.  Whereas I need this compression to be carried out in memory, as I am writing multiple images to disk (using a binary writer).

Comment: unless you have an algorithm to convert between these two formats I am  afraid the method mentioned in the question is only way to go.

Comment: Do you need JPG or any compressed format would work (like ZIP?) for your case? (You may also to look into DirectShow API to actually store video).

Comment: Ah no, really?  That's bad news (unless anyone happens to have such an algorithm?).  It doesn't have to be a compressed JPG, could be ZIP, PNG or something else as long as the compression is fast and the compressed image is small, I can deal with it when reading it back in. However, I cant store the video directly as I capture more than just the color information for each frame (such as depth data and body data) but I will check out DirectShow for sure!

Comment: Compressing using gzip seems to slow performance down as well :-s